# objectForKey returns nil for NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am using the following code to set a value into NSUserDefaults using Swift. Here is my code:

```
let key = "ticker"
let currencyTickerData = [key:"USD"]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currencyTickerData, forKey: key)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

let tickerVal : [NSString]? = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key)) as? [NSString]

print(tickerVal)
```

For some reason, tickerVal is nil. Why is this? As far as I can tell, it should return "USD."

Comment: a similar question with solution was just posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26424240/save-data-of-a-label-in-swift/26425574#26425574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserDefaults uses NSDictionary instead of Swift's dictionary type. You can explicitly type tickerVal as an NSDictionary like so:

```
let key = "ticker"
let currencyTickerData: NSDictionary = [key:"USD"]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(currencyTickerData, forKey: key)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

let tickerVal = (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key)) as NSDictionary

print("\(tickerVal)")
```

Comment: This prints "{\n    ticker = USD;\n}"

Comment: What do you want it to print? If you only want tickerVal to be "USD" use `let tickerVal: NSString = ((NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key)) as NSDictionary)[key] as NSString` instead

Answer (score 0):

It is same code that will save you're date:

```
var myValue:NSString = "USD"

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myValue, forKey:"ticker")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

var myOutput: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ticker")
println(myOutput)
```

Comment: This prints "Optional(USD)"